# Sometimes my dog refuses to eat, just sits next to his bowls and does nothing

Tags: dogs, psychology, anxiety

I've got a 2 year old parsons russell terrier, Bentley. He works with me - we do dog boarding and dog sitting from my home and we always have at least one other dog over. Therefore I can never leave his food bowl like i would otherwise because the other dogs will steal it. Most of the time when I put his bowl in front of him he would just sit and stare at me. He doesn't look scared, he just stares and refuses to sometimes even sniff the food. I try to leave him in the kitchen alone to eat but when I come back he hasn't moved at all.

When we don't have any dogs over I leave his bowl on the floor and he will come by himself and eat when he wants to. But that rarely happens, we have dogs over 99% of the time and I can't risk the other dogs getting an upset tummy because of Bentley's food.

All other dogs would eat their meals so nicely, and Bentley would watch them eat but wouldn't touch his own food. I mix some delicious wet food with his dry food and at times I have to put pieces of cheese in it so he will even agree to eat it.

I know he's not THAT picky because he eats his dry food without anything else in it without issues when it's left on the ground. I need an advice on how to teach him to eat what I give him? Because he THROWS UP when he doesn't eat! After having breakfast and skipping lunch he would throw up yellow foam just an hour before dinner! As far as I know it's his stomach telling me it's empty. I know in the wild they can go days without eating, but I'm tired of cleaning throw up that sometimes ends on the carpet or bed, and I'm tired of running through the flat when I hear him about to throw up so I can move him to a hard floor.

I also must say that I myself is a very anxious and problematic person - my family slowly drove me insane in my childhood and I ended up with many psychological issues. Nevertheless I'm 20 and my family still is driving me insane. I get mad (mostly at myself) a lot and I think Bentley can feel it, but there is nothing I can do about it as my family refuses to believe I have any issues at all. Until I make enough money to pay for my own therapy, I'm stuck with anger and anxiety issues.

Also Bentley goes to hide whenever anyone around talks too loudly or yells, like if anyone plays a ps3 game and gets mad at the character dying, he would run away. Even if the other dogs around will see the yelling as play and fun and would jump on me to play!  I need him to feel relaxed no matter what's going on around. He is such a perfect dog other than these 2 issues. Please help?

Comment: Can you feed Bentley in a separate room from the other dogs? As a side note, depending on where you live there are probably therapy options available with sliding scale fees based on what you can afford.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly possible that your dog doesn't like the brand of food. When I give my dogs a brand they don't like, they will refuse to eat it. Try changing to a different brand with different ingredients and see if this helps.

For the second issue, try getting a thundershirt or thundershirt knockoff. They help a dog to feel more secure because it feels as if someone is holding them.